# how to assign JSON array of object data to appropriate list of T

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I have two types SalesData and CollectionData. These two types are entirely different type. So when I passed the data to front end i created dynamic data type and passed the data to front end depending on the call.

While receiving data back, I created json data which is array of objects.

Now I am in situation how do i assigned incoming arrays to List or List according to the type.

This is what I have done.

```
public ActionResult DownloadDataInExcel(List<object>data, int type)
        {
            if (type == (int)MyEnum.Sales)
            {
                var mycontacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SalesData>>(data.ToString());

                foreach (var item in mycontacts)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Name}-{item.City}-{item.Country}");
                }
            }else
            {
                var mycontacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CollectionData>>(data.ToString());

                foreach (var item in mycontacts)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{item.Name}-{item.City}-{item.Country}");
                }
            }

            //to do: Convert data to Excel File

            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }
```

Comment: did u successfully deserialize your json to either of type `SalesData` or `CollectionData`?

Comment: No. I think issue is I am passing array of array from ajax.

Comment: Please write the JSON and class for SalesData and CollectionData. You might have issue in the structure. We can help if you give complete information

Comment: Problem was data I have been passing via ajax was causing the error. I passed json object after stringifying and received as string in my method. "public ActionResult DownloadDataInExcel(string data, int type)".

Comment: i want to ask one question is that, you dont know incoming json datatype and in action method you want to deserialize into either of type SalesData or CollectionData ?

Comment: yes I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need a generic method to deserialize your incoming json to appropriate `List<>` object

```
public static List<T> DeserializeList<T>(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
}
```

2) Here I create an console app for your demonstration purpose.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json1 = @"[{'Id1':'1','Name1':'Mike','Age1':43},{'Id1':'2','Name1':'Anna','Age1':56}]";
        string json2 = @"[{'Id2':'1','Name2':'Mike','Age2':43},{'Id2':'2','Name2':'Anna','Age2':56}]";

        //Pass json1 and deserialize into list of Sample1
        var sample1List = DeserializeList<Sample1>(json1);
        sample1List.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Id1: {x.Id1},  Name1: {x.Name1}, Age1: {x.Age1}"));

        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        //Pass json2 and deserialize into list of Sample2
        var sample2List = DeserializeList<Sample2>(json2);
        sample2List.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Id2: {x.Id2},  Name2: {x.Name2}, Age2: {x.Age2}"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static List<T> DeserializeList<T>(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
    }
}

class Sample1
{
    public string Id1 { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public int Age1 { get; set; }
}


class Sample2
{
    public string Id2 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public int Age2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @istudent, view the answer might be it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try-catch`

```
try
{
     var someresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type1>(data.ToString());
     // data was Type1 indeed, deal with Type1
}
catch{} 
try
{
     var someresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type2>(data.ToString());
     // data was Type2 indeed, deal with Type2
}
catch{}
```

Comment: exception message is "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Comment: well you would always have exception in one of these `catch`es as the type would only match one. but if you are getting exception for both then your passed item does not match any of them.

Comment: I think i am getting exception as i was passing array of array via ajax. i will get back once i successfully create json object. Thank you Ashkan.